# google geolocation, valid request, but no results returned?

Tags: http-status-code-404, google-geolocation

I have been trying to access the geolocation api to locate cell towers
I'm no expert at http posts. All I receive is the http code 404.
I have concatenated the geolocation web-address, my api-key and the json request. (without newlines/spaces)

```
https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?
key=myAPIkey
{"homeMobileNetworkCode":2,"homeMobileCountryCode":505,"cellTowers":[{"mobileCountryCode":505,"mobileNetworkCode":2,"locationAreaCode":38501,"cellId":209715676}],"radioType":"WCDMA","considerIp":"false"}
```

http code 404: notFound geolocation 404 The request was valid, but no results were returned.

I have tried various valid cells, and I cannot believe google doesn't know about any of them!

So I'm none the wiser, it seems the request is valid, but have I made a basic mistake...

My http post method is:

```java
  public void getGeo(Cell cell)        // cell: mcc, mnc, lac, cid, type, lat, lon, address
  {
    try
    {
      String json = formJSON(cell);
      String query = GEO + KEY + json;
      URL url = new URL(query);
      HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
      int code = connection.getResponseCode();
      if (code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
      {
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader reader;
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
          response.append(line);
        }
        reader.close();
        String result = response.toString();
        parseJSON(result);
        this.address = geocodeLocation();
        if (!this.error)
        {
          cell.setLat(this.latitude);
          cell.setLon(this.longitude);
          cell.setAcc(this.accuracy);
          cell.setAddress(this.address);
        }
      }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      this.error = true;
      this.errMsg = e.toString();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems, I had made a GET request and not a POST request. I  seem to have worked it out...